# SVG link doesn't work

Tags: javascript, svg

I have created an SVG image file. Within the file I have added some links to some of the SVG components by wrapping them in an a tag:

```
     <a xlink:href="/svg/index.html" target="_top">
    <g id="p100000Box" transform="translate(0, 0)" visibility="visible">
    <rect width="200" height="160" rx="20" ry="20"></rect>
    <line x1="0" y1="35" x2="200" y2="35"></line>
    </g>
```

When I open the image file in a web browser the links work fine,

I have now embedded the image file into a web page using

```
<embed id="systemNavigation" class="systemNavigation" src="../images/svg/SystemNavigation.svg" type="image/svg+xml" />
```

But the links don't work any more. I have also tried embedding it using:

```
<object id="systemNavigation" class="systemNavigation" data="../images/svg/SystemNavigation.svg" type="image/svg+xml" />
```

but this doesn't work either.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see a closing `</a>` tag, perhaps you forgot to copy it?

Comment: Sorry, missed that in the post, but it is in the code.

Comment: Please provide a live example. I don't think links will copy into a saved SVG image embedding...

Comment: I'm not sure what happened I didn't change anything (I promise) but it seems to have started to work. It might have been a caching problem!